# Syntax highlighting for python output?

Tags: python, color, r

When using R in the console, one can use the package [`colorout`](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/colorout.html) to highlight R outputs.

Does there exist such a thing for Python output? I am mostly interested in:

- easily distinguishing commands lines from output lines
- easily distinguishing between `list`, `dict`, `int`, `str`, objects, bare `print` outputs etc.
- easily spotting Python error output
- making the console feel more comfortable to the eye

Comment: Far away from optimum, you can use xterm escape sequences for coloring on linux, but you would have to turn it off on windows. the first link which I found about it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt

Comment: @danielalder The Python package `colorama` colors console outputs on Linux and Windows. On Linux escape sequences are used, on Windows it should be WinAPI calls.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it could. There are two python script that could do so: [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) and [ipython](http://ipython.org/). You may start them either directly or from python interpreter.

`bpython`

[image: bpython shot]

`ipython qtconsole`

[image: ipython shot]

Comment: Wow, these are great! Funny though how their philosophy differs from `colorout` in that they color *input* not *output* (I guess this is because one quite doesn't use output for the same things in R and Python). Just before I mark the answer as accepted, do you know whether there are options in IPython or BPython to parse and color *output*? Like distinguishing list from dictionnaries with colors, or strings from ints?

Answer (score 2):

Simply install [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) with `pip install colorama` then you can use it with:

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
print (colorama.Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print (colorama.Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
```

[image: Screenshot]

If you would like a simpler way of coloring output, among other things, you should take a look at [click](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/click/) and the `secho()` command which detects if colorama is installed and uses it automatically, it also handles stripping out the color when output is being rediriected, etc.

```
import click
click.clear()  # Clear the terminal window
click.secho('Hello World!', fg='green')
click.secho('Some more text', bg='blue', fg='white')
click.secho('ATTENTION', blink=True, bold=True)
```

[image]

Comment: This does not parse your output, does it? I guess I would then have to hightlight myself strings, numerics, exceptions etc.

Comment: @lago-lito If you want to have *syntax highlighting*, you should call it by its name, the way how you describe it is easy to overlook (i did and steve also did)